# Error in Oracle procedure, object is invalid

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Where is the bug? Compilation ends with errors and I have no idea where I'm going wrong.

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE make_payoff(user_id_argument number) 
is
begin
payoff_amount:= 0;
CURSOR Clicks IS
    SELECT c.cpc FROM click as c JOIN widget w ON w.id = c.widget_id JOIN website web ON web.id = w.website_id WHERE web.user_id = user_id_argument AND c.payoff_id IS NULL;
BEGIN
FOR Click IN Clicks
LOOP
    payoff_amount:= payoff_amount + Click.cpc;
END LOOP;

INSERT INTO payoff (user_id, amount) VALUES (user_id_argument, payoff_amount);
COMMIT;
end;
```

I'm getting:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00905: object S10306.MAKE_PAYOFF is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

EDIT:
I've fixed Cursor name but error is the same

Comment: `FOR Click IN Click` ??? First of all your cursor is has the same name, as your field. Even I'm confused, let alone PL/SQL interpreter.

Comment: The OP needs to use SHOW ERROR and then fix their own syntax errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the error you get when you try to *use* the procedure. Not the error you get when you *compile* it. You need to find the error you get when you compile the procedure, probably using `show errors` and attempt to solve that problem.

Your problem is that `for click in click` should be `for click in clicks`... Not the extra `s`, so you are looping through the cursor.

Additionally, in your cursor you've written `FROM click as c`, which is not valid in Oracle. This should be `FROM click c`

And two BEGINs... remove the first one.

[Alex Poole has noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122321/sql-error-i-oracle-procedure/17122358#comment24776696_17122358) that you've also not declared the type of the variable payoff_amount. You should declare this as a number:

```
payoff_amount number := 0;
```

**However**, there is no need to do this, no need to loop, no need to use a procedure at all. This is possible with a single SQL statement:

```
insert into payoff (user_id, amount)
select 'user_id_argument', sum(c.cpc)
  from click c 
  join widget w 
    on w.id = c.widget_id 
  join website web 
    on web.id = w.website_id 
 where web.user_id = user_id_argument 
   and c.payoff_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: fixed but error is the same. I need a procedure it's just part of my code.

Comment: Whether or not you need a procedure, you do not need a cursor or a loop or a variable, @user967225. Of course the error is the same, you're looking at the wrong error, please see the first sentence of my answer.

Comment: Also you have two BEGIN statements @user967225.

Comment: i use it like this: EXECUTE make_payoff(1);

Comment: That's not the error you get when you compile it @user967225. Have you removed the first BEGIN? When you compile it type `show errors` afterwards to see the actual errors.

Comment: Actually you've covered more than I realised so my answer is a bit repetitive... if you add setting the payoff_amount type I'll remove mine.

Comment: That comment took a while to process @Alex :-). Done, thanks.

Comment: Yes @Ben 'begin' was the case! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You missed `s`.

```
FOR Click IN Clicks
LOOP
    payoff_amount:= payoff_amount + Click.cpc;
END LOOP;
```

Anyway, don't name variables and cursors so close to database fields. Add some prefix, for example, to differentiate easily.

Answer (score 0):

I created a procedure for my user under the user sys. When starting the procedure, I received the same errors as yours. The procedure was valid. Recompiling the object under different users did not help solve the problem. I drop the procedure and created it as my user. Problem solved.